# SonarQube LDAP Plugin Not starting/working

Tags: configuration, active-directory, ldap, sonarqube

So I got sonarqube working and added the LDAP plugin then I config the plugin. Followed the instructions on the LDAP plugin page. See Below. I was able to start sonar and it starts with the plugin configured. There is no issues on startup. I am able to reach the AD server, you would see an error if it couldn't.

I am using:

sonar-ldap-plugin-2.1.0.507.jar
and
sonarqube-6.2

Log below config

```
 LDAP configuration
 General Configuration
sonar.security.realm=LDAP
ldap.url=ldaps://adaddres:636
ldap.bindDn=username
ldap.bindPassword=password
sonar.forceAuthentication=true

 User Configuration
ldap.user.baseDn=ou=Users,dc=name,dc=com
ldap.user.request=(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={login}))
ldap.user.realNameAttribute=cn
ldap.user.emailAttribute=mail

Spawning intermediate process...
Spawning daemon process...
--> Wrapper Started as Daemon
Using tick timer.
server listening on port 32000.
Command[0] : java
Command[1] : -Dsonar.wrapped=true
Command[2] : -Djava.awt.headless=true
Command[3] : -Xms8m
Command[4] : -Xmx8m
Command[5] : -Djava.library.path=./lib
Command[6] : -classpath
Command[7] : ../../lib/jsw/wrapper-3.2.3.jar:../../lib/sonar-application-6.2.jar
Command[8] : -Dwrapper.key=UFNH8UhRw1QG0rs4
Command[9] : -Dwrapper.port=32000
Command[10] : -Dwrapper.jvm.port.min=31000
Command[11] : -Dwrapper.jvm.port.max=31999
Command[12] : -Dwrapper.debug=TRUE
Command[13] : -Dwrapper.pid=8416
Command[14] : -Dwrapper.version=3.2.3
Command[15] : -Dwrapper.native_library=wrapper
Command[16] : -Dwrapper.service=TRUE
Command[17] : -Dwrapper.cpu.timeout=10
Command[18] : -Dwrapper.jvmid=1
Command[19] : org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp
Command[20] : org.sonar.application.App
Launching a JVM...
WrapperManager class initialized by thread: main  Using classloader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@33909752
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
Wrapper Manager: JVM #1
Running a 64-bit JVM.
Wrapper Manager: Registering shutdown hook
Wrapper Manager: Using wrapper
Load native library.  One or more attempts may fail if platform specific libraries do not exist.
Loading native library failed: libwrapper-linux-x86-64.so  Cause: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no wrapper-linux-x86-64 in java.library.path
Loaded native library: libwrapper.so
Calling native initialization method.
Inside native WrapperManager initialization method
Java Version   : 1.8.0_121-b13 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
Java VM Vendor : Oracle Corporation
Startup runner thread started.
Control event monitor thread started.
WrapperManager.start(org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp@85ede7b, args[]) called by thread: main
Communications runner thread started.
Open socket to wrapper...Wrapper-Connection
Failed attempt to bind using local port 31000
Opened Socket from 31001 to 32000
Send a packet KEY : UFNH8UhRw1QG0rs4
handleSocket(Socket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=32000,localport=31001])
accepted a socket from 127.0.0.1 on port 31001
read a packet KEY : UFNH8UhRw1QG0rs4
Got key from JVM: UFNH8UhRw1QG0rs4
send a packet LOW_LOG_LEVEL : 1
send a packet PING_TIMEOUT : 0
send a packet PROPERTIES : (Property Values)
Start Application.
send a packet START : start
Received a packet LOW_LOG_LEVEL : 1
Wrapper Manager: LowLogLevel from Wrapper is 1
Received a packet PING_TIMEOUT : 0
PingTimeout from Wrapper is 0
Received a packet PROPERTIES : (Property Values)
Received a packet START : start
calling WrapperListener.start()
Waiting for WrapperListener.start runner thread to complete.
WrapperListener.start runner thread started.
WrapperSimpleApp: start(args) Will wait up to 2 seconds for the main method to complete.
WrapperSimpleApp: invoking main method
2017.03.09 15:47:38 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /root/sonarqube-6.2/temp
2017.03.09 15:47:38 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[es]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-0.b13.el7_3.x86_64/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djna.nosys=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/root/sonarqube-6.2/temp -javaagent:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-0.b13.el7_3.x86_64/jre/lib/management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer /root/sonarqube-6.2/temp/sq-process1338894911459281579properties
Send a packet START_PENDING : 5000
read a packet START_PENDING : 5000
JVM signalled a start pending with waitHint of 5000 millis.
Send a packet START_PENDING : 5000
WrapperSimpleApp: start(args) end.  Main Completed=false, exitCode=null
2017.03.09 15:48:06 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is up
2017.03.09 15:48:06 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[web]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-0.b13.el7_3.x86_64/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.management.enabled=false -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/root/sonarqube-6.2/temp -javaagent:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-0.b13.el7_3.x86_64/jre/lib/management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/server/*:/root/sonarqube-6.2/lib/jdbc/postgresql/postgresql-9.4.1209.jre7.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer /root/sonarqube-6.2/temp/sq-process3363637881001490888properties
send a packet PING : ping
Received a packet PING : ping
Send a packet PING : ok
read a packet PING : ok
Got ping response from JVM
send a packet PING : ping
2017.03.09 15:48:51 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[web] is up
2017.03.09 15:48:51 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[ce]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-0.b13.el7_3.x86_64/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/root/sonarqube-6.2/temp -javaagent:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-0.b13.el7_3.x86_64/jre/lib/management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/server/*:./lib/ce/*:/root/sonarqube-6.2/lib/jdbc/postgresql/postgresql-9.4.1209.jre7.jar org.sonar.ce.app.CeServer /root/sonarqube-6.2/temp/sq-process6807607337463053511properties
send a packet PING : ping
Received a packet PING : ping
read a packet PING : ok
Got ping response from JVM
2017.03.09 15:49:07 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[ce] is up
2017.03.09 15:49:07 INFO  app[][o.s.application.App] SonarQube is up
```

Comment: So.. what's the question ? and if any error, what do you see in _web.log_ ?

Comment: Sonarqubes documentation states:<br/>
<br/>
1. Configure the LDAP plugin by editing the SONARQUBE_HOME/conf/sonar.properties file (see table below)  
2. Restart the SonarQube server and check the log file for:  
  
INFO org.sonar.INFO Security realm: LDAP ...  
INFO o.s.p.l.LdapContextFactory Test LDAP connection: OK  
3.Log into SonarQube  
4.On log out users will be presented login page (/sessions/login), where they can choose to login as technical user or a domain user by passing appropriate credentials

Comment: When I try to login using the ldap creds it does not work. I have verified that I am using the right creds. But I can't log in.

Comment: Also web.log shows Test LDAP connection on ldaps://adserver:636: OK
2017.03.10 14:02:15 INFO  web[][org.sonar.INFO] Security realm started